# Java repaint not working correctly

Tags: java, canvas, panel, paint, repaint

i use the java repaint method , it repaints, but the update is only seen when I either click on the canvas or resize the panel. How can I fix this ? What causes it?

Comment: Code...., please? or do you want us to guess.

Comment: Are you using only standard Swing components? Have you made a custom component?

Comment: Swing? AWT? SWT? We need more info to give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 15):

You need to call the method revalidate(). This forces the layout manager to update / repaint all its components.

Answer (score 2):

repaint() isn't actually repainting, it's just *requesting* a repaint of the component.

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to simply grab the Graphics object from the component you wish to paint. Then just invoke a paint method on the Graphics object. For example:

```
g = component.getGraphics(); 
draw(g);
```

Comment: this is actually very useful when already on the swing thread